# Nested Queries In ASP.Net Without Async

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have the following code and basically I want it go step by step using the If statements. When I run this however I get this asp error: "This command requires an asynchronous connection. Set "Asynchronous Processing=true" in the connection string." 
On this bit of code:
"addToTable.BeginExecuteReader();"

However I do not want it to by async I want it to run the subsequent queries only if the previous conditions are met.

Full code is below:

```
string dataset="";
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
            {
                if (name != null && carId != null)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(st))
                    {


                        string getCar = "SELECT * FROM [Car] WHERE CarId = @carId";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getCarData, con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carId", carId);


                        using (cmd)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                            if (data.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (data.Read())
                                {
                                    if (data["available"].ToString() == "0")
                                    {
                                        data.Close();
                                        SqlCommand getParts = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [CarCustomer] WHERE UserId = @UserId AND car=@carId", con);
                                        getParts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"]);
                                        getParts.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carId", carId);
                                        SqlDataReader grabRows = getParts.ExecuteReader();
                                        if (grabRows.HasRows)
                                        {
                                            grabRows.Close();
                                            SqlCommand updateTable = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Table1] SET salesAmount=5 WHERE UserId=1", con);

                                            updateTable.BeginExecuteReader();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            grabRows.Close();
                                            SqlCommand addToTable = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Table1] (salesAmount)  Values("1")", con);

                                            addToTable.BeginExecuteReader();
                                        }
                    dataset="good"

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return dataset;
```

Comment: Yes that did that trick. Thx very much for the suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `BeginExecuteReader` command use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` , because `ExecuteNonQuery` is used to perform query like insert,update and delete where as for Gettting data Read method is used.

one more thing `BeginExecuteReader`method is used to perfrom asncy read operation so if you dont want that than just use `ExecuteReader`method to get data.

Read [**SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  - 
You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.